# Laravel mix skipping one scss line

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, webkit, laravel-mix

I'm developing a Laravel project in Laravel 5.4.
I use the Laravel mix package for css, mixing scss files. Today I added to my personal scss file these lines

```
span.dots-on-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

but after mixing the result I had is only

```
span.dots-on-overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
}
```

I don't understand the reason why the line **-webkit-box-orient: vertical;** is missing, or maybe skipped.

The css has no errors since I pasted it from the style attribute in html.

Thanks in advance if you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Can I Use?](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_box-orient) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient) indicate that this parameter is deprecated and state "Do not use it on production sites facing the Web".

I suspect it's seen as an invalid directive by the SCSS compiler and removed, especially if you're using something like [the polyfill plugin](https://laravel-mix.com/extensions/polyfill) for post-processing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't use that plugin, but anyway you led me to this
`span.dots-on-overflow {
    /* autoprefixer: off */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    /* autoprefixer: on */
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}`
which works within laravel mix

Comment: @AntonioMuzzolini Ah, you're using PostCSS perhaps. Glad that pointed you in the right direction. You may be able to turn off this feature entirely by tweaking the PostCSS config: https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/css-preprocessors#postcss-plugins